# Overlap of left cosets and right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index $r$. Let $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\beta_i\}$ be complete sets of right and left coset representatives, respectively. Then,
\begin{align*}
G= \bigsqcup_{i=1}^r H\alpha_i = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^r \beta_iH.
\end{align*}

My question is this: Is it always true, possibly after reordering the cosets, that $H\alpha_i \cap \beta_iH \neq \emptyset$ for every $i\in \{1,\ldots,r\}$? Any hints on this? I can prove it when $G$ is finite, but my proof doesn't work when $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Proof sketched in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_finite_index_has_a_left_transversal_that_is_also_a_right_transversal .